# Why does CopyFile2 replace CopyFile and CopyFileEx?

Tags: c++, api, microsoft-metro, file-copying

I was talking with a friend recently who told me that [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are not allowed in C++ Metro applications(which appears to be correct). Why is this? And why did they put forward an odd replacement named [CopyFile2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

All of them copy a file, so why ban part of the established API to put forward a new function to figure out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The general stance taken with the metro APIs has been "if there is an Ex function or something supersedes it, you have to call the new one."  Same goes for the 8-bit-string (misnamed "ANSI encoding" for historical reasons) versions of functions.  Among other benefits, this keeps the code size down for Windows RT.
2. Let's look analytically at `CopyFile2`...  For one, the options parameter is now a structure which has a size as the first member.  I would argue this is better for future extensibility than the approach taken by `CopyFileEx`.  This allows Microsoft to add new options while maintaining binary compatibility with older callers.  (Microsoft can extend the length of the structure, then check `dwSize` to determine what version of the structure you have, and adapt its behavior accordingly.)  This alone makes it more future proof than `CopyFileEx` which would require a function signature change (hence an entirely new function) to add a single option.  (I haven't read carefully, maybe they *did* already add an option in `CopyFile2` as well...)

Comment: There's a wider rule of "If there's an Ex function, they wish they could go back in time and do it that way to begin with", often with an added, "look, we're very sorry, look it's better in the Ex version, okay". Though mostly, that's only with the benefit of hindsight. We've all have code we wish we could blast away, and if we get that chance things end up cleaner (most of the time).

Comment: @JonHanna - In truth, I personally think some of the `Ex` functions are needless cruft which in practice pervert simple and elegant interfaces.  (Notice by contrast how rare it is in the Unix world to change the signature of a syscall - you might say for better or for worse.)  That said, I'm attempting to illustrate the thinking that went into this.

Comment: It's the other side of the same coin, letting them get rid of cruft by having just one function (though on consideration, there are some Ex forms where it's harder to see the need than with others).